# Using a where statement to update a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`currentQuarter`) which looks like

```
  CODE  SIP  ...                 STATUS  STATUS_CHANGE_DATE
0   AA  YES  ...                CURRENT          2019-01-01
1   AA  YES  ...                 LEAVER          2019-02-05
2   AA  YES  ...                 LEAVER          2019-09-03
3   AA  YES  ...                 JOINER          2019-01-05
4   AA  YES  ...                CURRENT          2019-03-08
```

I am trying to change the `STATUS` of any record to `CURRENT` where the `STATUS` is not `CURRENT` and the `STATUS_CHANGE_DATE` is in the future.  So in this example the `referencePeriodStartDate` is 2019-07-25.  Which would mean the third records `STATUS` field would change to `CURRENT`:

```
  CODE  SIP  ...                 STATUS  STATUS_CHANGE_DATE
0   AA  YES  ...                CURRENT          2019-01-01
1   AA  YES  ...                 LEAVER          2019-02-05
2   AA  YES  ...                CURRENT          2019-09-03
3   AA  YES  ...                 JOINER          2019-01-05
4   AA  YES  ...                CURRENT          2019-03-08
```

I can filter the `df` to create the query to find the records however I can't get the `where` statement to change the affected records:

```
referencePeriodStartDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(referenceDate , '%d/%m/%Y')
    not_current = currentQuarter['STATUS'].isin(leaverList) 
    currentQuarter['STATUS_CHANGE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(currentQuarter['STATUS_CHANGE_DATE'], errors='coerce')
    currentQuarter['STATUS_CHANGE_DATE'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') 
    referenceError = currentQuarter['STATUS_CHANGE_DATE'] > referencePeriodStartDate


currentQuarter['STATUS'] = np.where(not_current & referenceError, "CURRENT", currentQuarter['STATUS'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check which dates in `STATUS_CHANGE_DATE` are greater than today's, and use the result to index the dataframe and set the `STATUS` to `CURRRENT` accordingly:

```
df['STATUS_CHANGE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.STATUS_CHANGE_DATE)
df.loc[df.STATUS_CHANGE_DATE.gt(referencePeriodStartDate), 'STATUS'] = 'CURRENT'

   CODE  SIP   STATUS STATUS_CHANGE_DATE
0   AA  YES  CURRENT         2019-01-01
1   AA  YES   LEAVER         2019-02-05
2   AA  YES  CURRENT         2019-09-03
3   AA  YES   JOINER         2019-01-05
4   AA  YES  CURRENT         2019-03-08
```